# how to enter current date and time as 00:00:00 in one cell in excel

Tags: excel

I need start time and end time of any day given.

[image]

Start time would be current date followed by 00:00:00 and end time would be the current date and time.

For end date I used =NOW(). But for start time if I give =TODAY() 00:00:00 it shows error.

how to enter current date and time as 00:00:00 in one cell in excel?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have done is absolutely correct, you just have to use formula in start time cell as =TODAY() and format that cell with format painter similar to end time. It will result as you are expecting.

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply. I tried it and it worked out fine. Similarly if I need to have the end date as current date followed by 23:59:59, How can I do it? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of TODAY() is correct, it as should return 2014-10-09 00:00:00

So instead of

> =TODAY() 00:00:00

just use

> =TODAY()

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply. I tried it and it worked out fine. Similarly if I need to have the end date as current date followed by 23:59:59, How can I do it? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried it myself. I used =TODAY()+TIME(23,59,59). Please let me know if there is any other way.